# Jenkins SSH Plugin - Execute different shell script commands depending on task (build/release) - environment variable

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Using the same Jenkins job, is there a way to configure Jenkins SSH plugin to execute different commands depending on:

1. The task type: Maven build/release
2. An environment variable `mvn clean install -Denvironment=dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out the first option (the execution of different commands depending on the build type - build vs release)

1. We need the following **plugins**:

   - **Readonly Parameter plugin**: to pass a read only parameter
     (environment=pro) when launching a RELEASE.
   - **Environment Injector Plugin**: to pass a hidden parameter (environment=dev) when BUILDing.
   - **Release Plugin**
2. **Job configuration**:

   - Execution environment -> Configure release build
     Override build parameters checked
     String parameter RELEASE_VERSION
     String parameter DEVELOPMENT_VERSION
     Readonly String parameter environment - pro
   - Inject environment variables to the build process checked
     Properties content environment=dev
   - Post steps: You can access the declared variable (environment) in your shell script.

For instance:

```
if [ "$environment" = "dev" ]
then
    echo "development!"
fi
if [ "$environment" = "pro" ]
then
    echo "production!"
fi
```